# Data not saved to Realtime Database (Firebase)

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, android-jetpack-compose

I am connected to the Firebase Realtime Database:

[image]

**Data:**

```
data class Settings(
    val light_on: Boolean = false,
    val door_open: Boolean = false,
    val window_open: Boolean = false
)
```

**Repository code:**

```
class SettingsRepository @Inject constructor() {
    private val database: FirebaseDatabase = DatabaseModule.getFirebaseDatabaseInstance()

    fun getSettings() : Flow<HomeSettings?> {
        return callbackFlow {
            val dataRef = database.getReference("settings")

            val listener = dataRef.addValueEventListener(object: ValueEventListener {
                override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                   trySend(snapshot.getValue(HomeSettings::class.java))
                }

                override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                    cancel()
                }
            })

            awaitClose { dataRef.removeEventListener(listener) }
        }
    }

    fun createData(settings: Settings) : Flow<Settings> = flow {
        database.reference.child("settings").setValue(settings).await()
    }

    fun updateLightState(settings: Settings) : Flow<Settings> = flow {
        database.reference.child("settings").setValue(settings).await()
    }

    fun updateDoorState(settings: Settings) : Flow<Settings> = flow {
        database.reference.child("settings").setValue(settings).await()
    }

    fun updateWindowState(settings: Settings) : Flow<Settings> = flow {
        database.reference.child("settings").setValue(settings).await()
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
fun createData(){
    settingsRepository.createData(settings.value)
}

LaunchedEffect(scope) {
    viewModel.createData()
}
```

It simply does not show anything in the Real-time Database Firebase Console online at Google, which is strange. No errors are printed in the Debug output in Android Studio. I simply do not understand why this does not work.

**EDIT: No issues with the rules, they have been changed.**

[image]

---

**EDIT:** I made this, it shows me the name of the reference in the console, but, not the item. Do I need to set an ID manually, or make some config changes?

```
fun insert(item: Settings) : Flow<ResultResponse<String>> = callbackFlow {
        trySend(ResultResponse.Loading)

        reference.push().setValue(item)
            .addOnCompleteListener {
                if(it.isSuccessful)
                    trySend(ResultResponse.Success("Data inserted successfully"))
            }
            .addOnFailureListener {
                trySend(ResultResponse.Failure(it))
                cancel()
            }

        awaitClose { close() }
    }
```

Comment: Aside from my answer, if you consider at some point in time trying using [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/), I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-make-a-clean-architecture-android-app-using-mvvm-firestore-and-jetpack-compose-abdb5e02a2d8) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirestoreCleanArchitectureApp).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following method:

```
fun createData(settings: Settings) : Flow<Settings> = flow {
    database.reference.child("settings").setValue(settings).await()
}
```

Is defined to return a Flow. First of all, such a method is not recommended to return a Flow, since you are only adding some data to the database. Such a method should be a simple suspend function. A Flow is used when you need to send multiple values in sequence.

Besides that, you're creating a Flow but you never collect the result. So in my opinion, to add the data to the Realtime Database, I'd create a response class:

```
sealed class Response<out T> {
    data class Success<out T>(
        val data: T
    ): Response<T>()

    data class Failure(
        val e: Exception?
    ): Response<Nothing>()
}
```

And a `suspend` method in the repository class that looks like this:

```
suspend fun createData(settings: Settings): Response<Boolean> {
    return try {
        database.reference.child("settings").setValue(settings).await()
        Response.Success(true)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Response.Failure(e)
    }
}
```

Then I'd call it from a ViewModel class using a `viewModelScope`:

```
var response by mutableStateOf<Response<Boolean>>(Response.Success(false))
    private set

fun createData(settings: Settings) = viewModelScope.launch {
    response = repo.createData(settings)
}
```

And inside the screen I'd use:

```
when(val response = viewModel.response) {
    is Success -> Log.d(TAG, "Data added successfully.")
    is Failure -> Log.d(TAG, "Failed with: ${response.e?.message}")
}
```

One more recommendation, try to always handle errors.

Comment: **Alex**, thanks a lot. Please see my new method: `fun insert(item: Settings) : Flow<ResultResponse<String>> = callbackFlow {}`.

Comment: No, it's not correct. You should use a `callbackFlow` when you read data. However, I'm not sure I understand, why did you send that to me. Have you tried the solution in my answer? There is no `callbackFlow` involved there, but just a `suspend` function.

Comment: Alex, why is this approach *Incorrect*? I send it to you for **Feedback!**

Comment: I already said that a Flow is used when you need to send multiple values in sequence. You're adding data not reading it. So have you tried the solution in my answer?

Comment: **Alex**, you were correct about the `callbackFlow<T>` thank you so much.